# IF statement does not work in my code in python

Tags: python

I try to use IF in my code BUT dose not work

```
try:
    url = input (Fore.RED+'ENTER URL: ')
    url = "http://"+url
    print(Fore.WHITE+"\t CHECLIN URL "+url)
    req = requests.get(url)
    print(req)
    if  req =="<Response [200]>":
        print(Fore.GREEN+'SERVER IS ONLINE...')
    else:
        print(Fore.RED+"SERVER NOT FOUND...")
except:
    pass
```

ANOTHER TRY:

```
try:
    url = input (Fore.RED+'ENTER URL: ')
    url = "http://"+url
    print(Fore.WHITE+"\t CHECLIN URL "+url)
    req = requests.get(url)
    print(req)
    if "<Response [200]>" in req:
        print(Fore.GREEN+'SERVER IS ONLINE...')
    else:
        print(Fore.RED+"SERVER NOT FOUND...")
except:
    pass
```

BUT always "else" play
and jump from true "if"

Comment: `"<Response [200]>"` is just how `req` looks when you `print()` it.  It's not its _actual_ value or how you query it.

Comment: req.status_code==200 should work

Comment: I would suggest that you spend some time reading and understanding the examples in the Requests documentation.  See especially the section "Response Status Codes".  -https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/

Comment: You should write next line in the if section or if req.status_code==200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"<Response [200]>"`  is not the value of `req`, it's only the way it's represented in a string. To get the string representation of `req` pass it through `str`:

```py
if str(req) == "<Response [200]>":
    # ...
```

But anyway, it's better to use `req.status_code`:

```py
if req.status_code == 200:
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be because req is not equal to <[Response 200]>.
You should check for
if req.status_code == 200.

you should check req.__dict  to see what attributes are in req object.

Comment: I think that looking at `req.__dict` is not a good way to go about learning how a library works, or what methods a particular object provides.  This is what the library's documentation is for.  Reading the documentation and understanding the Python language itself are the two things that the OP should do to improve their understanding of how to use the Requests library.  Only if no documentation is available on a class should one result to looking in a low-level structure like `req.__dict`.